# Accidentally replaced my boot loader, new one isn't picking up old system

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, reinstall

#### Problem

Previously, I had a system dual-booting Linux Mint and Windows 10. Having become increasingly frustrated by some configuration issues that seemed to stem from my initial choice of `/home` partition, I decided to re-install Mint and fix the problem at the root, so to speak. My intent in doing this was to replace the old Linux Mint partitions without touching any of the Windows stuff. Unfortunately, in doing this, I must have accidentally selected the wrong partition on which to install GRUB. Now, when I boot my computer, Windows doesn't show up as an option in GRUB. The drive partition containing the Windows installation seems to still be there (the `C:\` drive), but I must have overwritten something related by mistake.

I was insufficiently cautious - I kept a backup of all my files, but did not make a full disk image, so I can't just roll back and try again.

Is there a solution that does not involve re-installing Windows from disk?

#### Further context, potentially useful

I have two relevant drives - an SSD (`nvme0n1`)for booting and an HDD (`sda`) for data. `fdisk -l` has the following output (skipping the `ram` stuff):

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x24419fa1

Device         Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/nvme0n1p2        1026048 249968639 248942592 118.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/nvme0n1p3      249970686 461053951 211083266 100.7G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      249970688 461053951 211083264 100.7G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E7593B53-7765-4219-8B4C-D029ADEA196E

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      264192 1743808511 1743544320 831.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1743808512 1953523711  209715200   100G Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Windows' `C:\` is on `nvme0n1p2`. Linux Mint has `\` on `nvme0n1p5`. `sda2` is an NTFS partition for documents and such, to be shared between the two. `sda3` is the `\home` for the Linux side. I don't know what the other partitions are for; I could guess, but a poor guess is what got me in this situation to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Kept doing research, found the solution was `sudo update-grub`. That found the Windows. Everything seems to be working so far, leaving this up in case someone else hits the problem.